# Trying to Change the Show Apps Button in GNOME

Tags: gnome, icons, ubuntu-dock, icon-themes, gnome-dash

I know there are similar questions to this already however I've followed them and I'm still experiencing some trouble. I'm trying to theme the show app grid icon in the dock with this icon https://github.com/gusbemacbe/suru-plus/blob/master/Suru++/apps/64/ubuntudash.svg

However, when I replace the `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` file with it I either get a blank white icon or no icon at all. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using the suru++ icon theme and it would be awesome to have all the icons in the dock uniform including the show apps launcher.

Comment: Ubuntu Version? are you using the ubuntu-dock which is pre-enabled or have you installed dash-to-dock?

Comment: @PRATAP Using Ubuntu 18.10 and I was initially using Dash-to-dock but have since reverted to the default Ubuntu dock. The settings applied when I was using Dash-todock have remained however

Comment: are you with Ubuntu Dock now? and wanted to use this image for the show-apps button?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I could manage to make it in 18.04 by editing the present shell theme..https://imgur.com/aJqd6zx seems like a lot of work to get this.. also i observed the .svg file look is not good comparing in the aspect of smoothness to the default one..

Comment: Okay I guess I’ll just scrap the idea for now. I wonder why the quality of the icon is lower as it downloaded as part of the same icon set. Anyway hopefully this changes in the future and I appreciate your help.

Comment: do you still want to stick with default ubuntu-dock? i think in `dash-to-panel` and `dash-to-dock` custom icons can be set very easily for show-apps icon..

Comment: can you check this.. i think.. its Ok here..https://i.stack.imgur.com/aajT9.png when the size is around 96px

Comment: I have no problem switching back to dash-to-dock. Yes! You are amazing, that looks perfect, how did you go about achieving this?

Comment: can you try it in `dash-to-panel` extension settings like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFDi1.png

Comment: It works with the dash-to-panel. However, if I want to continue using the dock style the icon will change right back. There are no options to change the icon in dash-to-dock settings.

Comment: yes for `ubuntu dock` or in `dash-to-dock` it requires editing the css file of present shell theme... think.. if you change the shell theme again you need to edit the css file.. anyway.. i will write the procedure in some time..

Answer (score 2):

***Ubuntu 18.10 with Suru++ Icon Theme..***

**just a work around to achieve what you are looking for with `ubuntu-dock` or `dash-to-dock`**

files required

1. modified `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg`
2. modified `gnome-shell.css`

both the files available here https://we.tl/t-xObT0VMoAV

need to copy all the files from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/` to `~/.themes` folder.
if `~/.themes` folder does not exist.. create the folder `~/.themes` first and then run the below command to copy the folder..

```
mkdir ~/.themes/myshell && mkdir ~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell && cp -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/* ~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell/
```

now replace the file `~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell.css` with the downloaded file `gnome-shell.css`

open gnome-tweaks and select `Myshell` theme under User Shell themes..(I assume you have installed this extension `User Themes`

[image]

now, Replace the image view-app-grid-symbolic.svg in the folder where you have `..../Suru++/actions/symbolic/` with the downloaded file.

[image]

Restart gnome-shell to see your favorite icon for the show-apps button..

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was in a `gnome-shell.css`? Which .css item I should change?

Comment: @CrafterKolyan Hi.. whats your OS??

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: ok.. the link i provided is expired..so we cannot download the edited files.. Do you want to change the showapps button? Do you have the image ready with you?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same thing. I've got image. I want to change showapps button.

Comment: ok can you share that image via a link..

Comment: is this link helpful? try this link.. https://askubuntu.com/a/1195231/739431

Comment: Thanks for the last link. Unfortunately it didn't help me. I've already solved my problem using "Dash to Panel" extension and in its' settings just changed `Behaviour -> Show applications icon -> Settings -> Custom Show Application icon`.

Comment: Didn't see you message about the link to the image. That's the one: https://github.com/B00merang-Project/Windows-10/blob/master/gnome-shell/assets/view-grid-symbolic.svg

Comment: ok thats fine.. yes Ubuntu-Dock only requiers editing css file or renaming the file.. Dash to Dock have that facility to use custom icon..