# How can I enable colour on my custom GNOME icons?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm a relatively new Linux user and I've been trying to customise my icons. However, when I try to change my "Show application" icon, it only appears in black and white.

The icon should look like this

[image: The icon should look like this]

but ends up looking like this

[image: looking like this]

Is there any way I can enable this icon to have colour?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and the svg file is here in a Google Drive link (I don't know if there's a better way to host it) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e680s8PoXJqECs6vFHdy9BR6nQfjg6DN/view?usp=sharing

I also used the terminal to move the new svg
```
sudo mv '/home/vincent/Downloads/view-app-grid-symbolic.svg' '/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/actions' 
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what exactly you mean. I haven't installed anything that modifies the dock and I've used Gnome Tweaks to edit stuff as you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/kxM0gph

I'm also trying to follow the link you sent me but I'm having trouble making it work. I also would've thought I would've found "view-app-grid-symbolic.svg" in the .css file so I could edit the colours from there, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCrxA.png let me write the steps for 18.04. but the steps are almost similar to this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1124586/739431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install "User Themes" gnome-shell extension from Ubuntu Software. (this is required to select the edited shell theme file)

   [image]
2. Create a `.themes` folder in home directory, if you have previously created it, then ignore this step.
3. Copy the required files from the default shell theme direcotry `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` with the below command in terminal

   Command:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.themes/myshell && mkdir ~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell && cp -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/* ~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell/
   ```
4. Delete the file `gnome-shell.css` and rename the file `ubuntu.css` as `gnome-shell.css`

   [image]
5. Close all, Open `gnome-tweaks` and choose `MyShell` from the drop down under User Themes

   [image]
6. Open the file `gnome-shell.css` from the `~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell/` directory and go to line number around 1301 and find below content.

   Content:

   ```
   .search-provider-icon,
   .list-search-result, .app-well-app .overview-icon,
   .app-well-app.app-folder .overview-icon,
   .show-apps .overview-icon,
   .grid-search-result .overview-icon {
     color: #eeeeec;
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 6px;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     transition-duration: 100ms;
     text-align: center; }
   ```

   Edit the Content like below, save & close:

   ```
   .search-provider-icon,
   .list-search-result, .app-well-app .overview-icon,
   .app-well-app.app-folder .overview-icon,
   .show-apps .overview-icon,
   .grid-search-result .overview-icon {
    color: #eeeeec;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition-duration: 100ms;
    text-align: center; }

   .show-apps .show-apps-icon { border: none; background-image: url(005-book.svg); background-size: contain; color: transparent; transition-duration: 0s; -st-background-image-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22); }

   .show-apps:hover .show-apps-icon, .show-apps:active .show-apps-icon, .show-apps:checked .show-apps-icon, .show-apps:focus .show-apps-icon { color: transparent; background-image: url(005-book.svg); -st-background-image-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28); transition-duration: 0.15s; }
   ```
7. Take a backup of the file `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` and delete it.
8. Copy the file 005-book.svg to `~/.themes/myshell/gnome-shell`

   [image]
9. Restart the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, this is great. I tried to follow the other guide but I thought I needed to download those unavailable files. Thank you so much for your help!