# How do I change the "Show Application" logo with an icon?

Tags: gnome, 19.10

I want to replace my "Show Application" logo with an .ico file, I want it to look like Unity 8.
I found the "show-applications-extension-symbolic.svg" in the "/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/actions/" and I tried to replace it with my converted ".ico file to .svg".
But it seems that it is impossible to convert an .ico file to .svg because they are different types of files.

Can you find a solution for this? This is how Unity 8 DE looks: [unity8.logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNNJo.jpg)

Thank you for your time :p

edit: I want to use the file as it is (if possible) but if the solution requires to convert the file, well, it's okay.
This is the .ico file in question (it is converted to .png because this website doesn't allow to send .ico files): [ubuntu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBSAb.png)
( If you have an svg of this image, please send )

Comment: do you hv the logo ready? is it in .ico format? do you want to use it as it is or image conversion is OK? please share the file.

Comment: I just care about the end result, I want my "Show Application" look like the "unity8.logo" I sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Workaround*** by Trail and Error

OS: Ubuntu 19.10
Shell Theme: Yaru

Additional Requirement: User-Themes Gnome Shell Extension.
(gnome-tweaks is also required if gsettings command line dont work for user-theme)

Create a local theme named MyTheme (or any other) `~/.local/share/themes/MyTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` with below content. (create the files if they dont exist)

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css");


.show-apps .show-apps-icon {
border: none;
background-image: url("file:///home/maduri/1.svg");
background-size: contain;
color: transparent; }

.show-apps:hover .show-apps-icon, .show-apps:active .show-apps-icon, .show-apps:checked .show-apps-icon, .show-apps:focus .show-apps-icon {
color: transparent; 
background-image: url("file:///home/maduri/1.svg"); }
```

change the image path in above content.

Select the "MyTheme" user theme from command line or via gnome-tweaks.

refresh the shell with Alt+F2 r Enter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked, how can I remove the padding on the icons? I want the "Show Applications" menu to appear like on Unity 8.